# Cocoa WebView Log out of Office365

Tags: cocoa, sharepoint, authentication, webview, office365

My application uses a WebView for getting access to an Office365 (SharePoint) site. The WebView inspects every request looking for a cookie, once the cookie is found the WebView is closed and the site is consulted using this cookie.

Now I need to give the option of changing the credentials to the user. To do it I delete all the cookies for the Office365 URL, open the WebView, and try access the site URL. The problem is that the validation cookie arrives in a request without asking for any credentials.

The only way that the web login form shows again is: clear the cookies, closing my app and relaunch.

How can I logout a user without closing my app?

Thanks